# Error al subir una foto al servidor php

Tags: php

estoy desarrollando una página con sistemas de login y subida de archivos a la misma. Tengo un problema en un formulario a la hora de almacenar la imagen que sube el usuario, el error es el siguiente:

```
    ( ! ) Warning: move_uploaded_file(/home/pw77389915/public_html/pe2/exposiciones/imagenes/background2.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/pw77389915/public_html/pe2/exposiciones/alta_expo.php on line 120
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0001  364856  {main}( )   .../alta_expo.php:0
2   0.0007  409232  move_uploaded_file ( )  .../alta_expo.php:120

( ! ) Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpA5CyzX' to '/home/pw77389915/public_html/pe2/exposiciones/imagenes/background2.jpg' in /home/pw77389915/public_html/pe2/exposiciones/alta_expo.php on line 120
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0001  364856  {main}( )   .../alta_expo.php:0
2   0.0007  409232  move_uploaded_file ( )  .../alta_expo.php:120
```

Mi código para añadir la imagen al servidor es el siguiente:

```
if(isset($_FILES["imagen"]) && $_FILES["imagen"]["name"]!==""){
            $imagen = $_FILES["imagen"]["name"];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"], SITE_ROOT."/"."imagenes"."/".$imagen);        
        }
        else{    
            echo "La imagen es obligatoria <br>";
            $correcto = false;
        }
```

Siendo SITE_ROOT lo siguiente: `define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));`

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pon en tu contexto un **`printf("%s/imagenes/%s",SITE_ROOT,$imagen);`** y verifica que la ruta que se muestra es correcta, por los mensajes parece que no lo es.

Comment: Para realizar un move_uploaded_file() la carpeta destino debe existir. Segun tu error esta carpeta no existe: `/home/pw77389915/public_html/pe2/exposiciones/imagenes/`.  Si realmente no quieres poner las imágenes en ese sitio, créate una nueva constante que apunte correctamente a tu carpeta correcta y úsala en lugar de SITE_ROOT, pues ésta usa  `__FILE__` que apunta al archivo que ejecuta el código, en tu caso `/home/pw77389915/public_html/pe2/exposiciones/alta_expo.php` y por eso coge la ruta `/home/pw77389915/public_html/pe2/exposiciones/` como SITE_ROOT y luego le agrega `/imagenes/`

Answer (score 0):

```
( ! ) Warning: move_uploaded_file(/home/pw77389915/public_html/pe2/exposiciones/imagenes/background2.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/pw77389915/public_html/pe2/exposiciones/alta_expo.php on line 120
```

Esta linea de error puede que te este dando porque la ruta especificada donde se guardará tu archivo, puede que no exista, si tu idea es que la ruta se cree al pasar el archivo debes hacer uso de

```
//Aqui debes colocar la ruta que quieres que se cree, es decir creara una carpeta con el nombre que tu le pongas: en este caso entras a una carpeta llamada ruta y creara un carpeta llamada ejemplo
$directorio = "ruta/ejemplo/";

mkdir($directorio, 0777) or die("No se puede crear el directorio de extracci&oacute;n");
```

`mkdir` sirve para crear carpetas donde puedes guardar de forma dinamica tus archivos, debes hacer eso antes de mover tu archivo. Porque si solo mueves el archivo y la ruta que especificas, puede que no exisa y no te va a funcionar.

Aclaracion: `move_uploaded_file` solo es para mover archivos al destino especificado, `mkdir` sirve para crear el directorio donde guardaras tu archivo

Consulta la documentacion de php para saber como funciona este proceso.